# 3-way switch has two separate circuit hot wires from the breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, smart-switch

I have an old 1921 home with a 3-way switch for the upstairs banister hallway. The switch locations are on either end of the staircase and it controls the track lighting on the 2nd floor.

I wanted to install a dimming smart switch, but the new switch requires a neutral. After taking everything apart (for got to label the original wiring :facepalm:) I realized that there's no neutral wire to be found. In addition, while I was working on one of the switch locations, I realized that there was still a hot wire at that location even after I had turned off the breaker and the lights lost power.

I continued to dig and found that the downstairs 3-way light switch had a hot wire on breaker #7 and the upstairs' hot wire is on breaker #20!?!?

I did a continuity check on all of the wires and this diagram is what I discovered.

Stairs Wire Diagram
[image: 3-way Stairs Diagram]

Lower Stairs Switch
[image: Lower-Stairs-switch-hot-and-wire-to-light]
[image: Lower-Stairs-switch-traveler]

Upper Stairs Switch
[image: Upper-Stairs-Switch-front-view]
[image: Upper-Stairs-Switch-hot-and-to-light]
[image: Upper-Stairs-Switch-traveler]

After some research is seems that this could be some variation of a Carter System 3-way, but what's strange is the two hot wires from different circuits. I decided to back out of the smart switch upgrade and just try to put things back the way it was and now I can't get the lights to turn on at all!

Getting at the wires in a way to run new wiring is impractical unless I start ripping out my kitchen ceiling and wall plaster to get at the existing wiring to replace.

How was this working before? How come I can't get it working now? Please help and thank you in advance for taking the time to help.

Bonus: Question, the smart switch requires a neutral in addition to two (2) travelers and a Common (Hot).  Is there any way to switch out one of the switches to accomplish this without running new wire?  Thanks again.

Comment: First thing to do if there are two breakers, is to move them together and place a handle tie between them.  Everything else is way above me.

Comment: @crip659 This doesn't sound like an intentional MWBC setup - that hallway light surely isn't intended to run on 240 v. Arranging the breakers as if they were MWBC, adjacent with a handle tie, would likely make the situation worse.

Comment: The only way that could be a Carter 3-way is if the wire you've labelled "Traveler" is in fact connected to Neutral somewhere.

Comment: @brhans, the wire that I have labeled "Traveler" is just a direct wire between both switches. When I used my multimeter to check continuity, this is the only wire in the boxes that indicated a connection.  The others were either Hot or had direct continuity with the wires in the light fixture.

Comment: @crip659 – Thank you for the comment. This is a home in the U.S. with 110V service.

Comment: Yes in a Carter 3-way that wire would connect the 2 switches as you've drawn, but it would *also* be connected to neutral ... somewhere. Not necessarily somewhere obvious though. Check for continuity between that wire and a known-good neutral - from a nearby outlet for example.

Comment: @GregHill  Probably not a true MWBC but OP should still have a way that both breakers are turned off for the next person.  Even if just a big honking sign.

Comment: @crip659 7 and 20 in a standard odd on one side, even on the other, alternating rows between the two hot legs panel will be on the same hot. So putting them on a typical double-breaker or handle-tied pair would be a 240V disaster. **However**, this would be the **perfect** situation to put in a handle-tied tandem half-size pair, which would put them on the same hot leg (bad for MWBC but good for this situation) and give you common shutoff.

Comment: given that both lamp wires run to the switches locations there's a neutral there somewhere.

Comment: Can you get us photos looking squarely into the backs of the boxes please?

Comment: You say "Getting at the wires in a way to run new wiring is impractical unless I start ripping out my kitchen ceiling and wall plaster to get at the existing wiring to replace."  Why do you say this?  The usual practice is to disconnect the old wiring at both ends and pull new behind the walls and ceiling without opening them.  It may be a chore, but you shouldn't have to tear anything up (maybe patch an intermediate pull hole or two if you're unlucky).

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one... You will need to dig into fixture box also to verify what and how many wires are there.  Assuming that the each switch box ONLY contains the three wires you have shown (none tucked way in the back of box,) then there must be a neutral in the fixture box. Assuming this is the case, my guess as to having 2 circuits present is this: 1) circuit 7 feeds various things on first floor; 2) circuit 20 feeds various things on 2nd floor; 3) the light was operating on what I refer to as a "split neutral" (line from one circuit feeding into neutral from a different circuit;) 4) the three way switching was actually happening on the NEUTRAL side rather than line side.
This is only way I can conceive of to match the layout you describe.

To fix the issues, will need to know for sure where every wire in all 3 boxes go to. Give some pics of the fixture box and double check no wires are hiding way in back of any box. Then with every wire disconnected from everything in every box, retrace each wire from end to end using continuity tests. (I prefer to use a long piece of wire connected to a particular wire and drag it to next box to check continuity thru that wire to find other end. This avoids any doubt of having both ends of same wire.) When determining "hot" wires, do so with a volt meter rather than non-contact detectors. Pay close attention to voltage readings. A 1 to 2 volt drop below line voltage at breaker can indicate reading an open neutral wire with line passing thru a load.

I know that sounds like a real chore, but with really old installations, they generally have been thru many alterations thru the decades and can be nearly impossible to figure out without identifying each wire end to end.